# How to solve ' Exception has occurred: TypeError coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found ' in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate average goals by team from a dataset of matches and came up with the following error- '*Exception has occurred: TypeError
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found*' My code is;

```
matches = open('matches.csv', 'r')
data_read = csv.reader(matches, delimiter = ',')
matches = []
for row in data_read:
    matches.append((row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]))

 team=['Bandari','Chemelil','Gor Mahia','Kakamega Homeboyz','Kariobangi Sharks','Kenya CB',
 'Leopards','Mathare Utd.','Mount Kenya United', 'Nzoia Sugar','Posta Rangers','Sofapaka',
 'Sony Sugar','Tusker','Ulinzi Stars','Vihiga United', 'Western Stima', 'Zoo']

results=[]
for file in matches:
    avgs=[]
    **for object in team:**
        goalsscored=0
        with open(file) as f:
            reader=csv.DictReader(f)
            rows=[ row for row in reader if row['Home_Team']==object]

            for row in rows:
                for rows in row[HTgoals]:
                    goalsscored=goalsscored + int(row['HTgoals'])


        with open(file) as f:
            reader=csv.DictReader(f)
            rows2=[ row for row in reader if row['Away_Team']==object]

            for row in rows2:
                for rows2 in row['ATgoals']:
                    goalsscored=goalsscored + int(row['ATgoals'])

            kk=df.apply(pd.value_counts) 
            avgs.append(goalsscored/kk) 
    results.append(avgs)
```

The error I get, which pops up at the line enclosed with double asteriks, is

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\betapp1\model_1.py", line 28, in <module>
with open(file) as f:
  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda2\Lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda2\Lib\runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code
mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda2\Lib\runpy.py", line 252, in run_path
return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, path_name)
```

My dataset consists of 4 values per row, the home team, the away team, goals scored by the home team and goals scored by the away team. An example is below;

```
Gor Mahia,Tusker,1,0
Mount Kenya United,Zoo,1,0
Sony Sugar,Western Stima,4,0
```

I expect the output to be a list with the average number of goals a team scores, but Im not getting any output

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your error is here:

```py
for file in matches:
    avgs=[]
    for object in team:
        goalsscored=0
        with open(file) as f: # error is here
            reader=csv.DictReader(f)
```

The `open` function is expecting `file` to be a string or file buffer, but it is a tuple that looks something like this `(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])`. If you specify the filenames that you are trying to open, then we can help further.